# Apple Watch Series 3 (WatchOS 8.8) cannot connect/pair to Xcode v15.0.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, watchkit, watchos

For some unknown reason, my apple watch is unable to sync with Xcode and I am unable to build to my Watch. In the Devices and Simulators window, it always shows my Apple Watch as "Connecting" and switches between the following messages:

"Waiting to reconnect to [NAME]’s Apple Watch/Xcode will continue when the operation completes." or "Previous preparation error: Unsupported wire protocol version: This host does not support the wire protocol version implemented by the device."

The only change that has happened between the apple watch connecting and the error occuring now is I updated my iPhone to IOS v.17.

I have tried to restart all devices, Xcode, Reinstall Xcode and nothing has worked. One thing to note is I am not apart of the Apple Developer Program so I will not have access to any of the diagnostic tools apart of that membership to diagnose this issue.